# FFmpeg identify non-IDR frame (I frame) as keyframe

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframes

It's a mov file. We use FFmpeg/FFprobe to process this file. There is a frame which is shown 'keyframe' (flags=K) in this file, but we found this frame is a non-IDR frame (only is I frame) using 264 stream analysis tool. Is it a bug of ffmpeg? How could we ensure the IDR frame?

3450 is that frame.
[image]
[image]

This is a brief info from ffprobe.

> `Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '***.mov':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : qt
>       minor_version   : 537199360
>       compatible_brands: qt
>       creation_time   : 2015-08-05 14:23:07
>     Duration: 00:07:36.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6400 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080p [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6009 kb/s, 29.97 fps (default)
>       Metadata:
>         handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
>         encoder         : H.264
>       Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
>       Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler`

Comment: What did the analyser report? It could be a recovery point. Can you share the file?

Comment: Hi, I add two pictures from stream analyser.

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: What do you mean by “ensure” the frame? To what end? Why is this a problem? Can you just parse the nal header?

Comment: Hi, SlimSCSI. Because I'd like to use '-ss' parameter. FFmpeg seeks to this frame which is I frame not IDR frame, and try to decode from this frame. But obviously, FFmpeg can't decode from this frame.

Comment: Hi, Gyan. Sorry, I can't share this file because of license.

Comment: It is probably a bug, I have reported the issue and found the cause:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9523